# curl configuring with certificate and enable with particular certificate in C

Tags: curl, openssl

I am using a cCURL to talk with webserver , now I need to enable the security part in the cCURL client code , I searched but could not get the info about how to add my own CA certificate and enable my client with particular cipher suit  like (ECC-CCM) ,... any info will be good ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check [manual page](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) and [sslcerts](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html) section

```
--ciphers <list of ciphers>
--cacert [file]
```

Comment: This helps when I am using in the command line mode , I need to add that it to my application code  using the curl C APIs ..